# React Native - Is it possible to see if a duplicate image is being uploaded?

Tags: react-native

So I'm uploading images and this is what console is printing out

```
[{"addPhoto": true}, {"fileName": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_9751f43a-6db0-4919-8b08-6e7407ecc62c.jpg", "fileSize": 374466, "height": 810, "type": "image/jpeg", "uri": "file:///data/
user/0/com.cheersfe/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_9751f43a-6db0-4919-8b08-6e7407ecc62c.jpg", "width": 1000}, {"fileName": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_a3b812b4-7dea-4117-b388-eae0980b6d9e.j
pg", "fileSize": 4429, "height": 300, "type": "image/jpeg", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.cheersfe/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_a3b812b4-7dea-4117-b388-eae0980b6d9e.jpg", "width": 400
}, {"fileName": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_f358db3e-ae5b-4135-8009-54ae9d56fdea.jpg", "fileSize": 4429, "height": 300, "type": "image/jpeg", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.cheersfe/cache/
rn_image_picker_lib_temp_f358db3e-ae5b-4135-8009-54ae9d56fdea.jpg", "width": 400}]
```

I want to be able to stop a user from uploading the same image multiple times. The issue is that React Native the image upload library I'm using caches it in memory with a unique uuid and path. How can I check if the image has already been uploaded?

[image]

Comment: What are module are you using to upload the pictures? If there is a way to store the original file name before you get your unique one, then you could store it in a list and for ever upload, check that the file name doesnt exists. If its impossible to do that, then you could compare the raw file data (read the file as string and then do comparison)

Comment: You could try get image path location (with file name ) and uploaded it with image , when the user try to use same image , you will need to check if there are image with same path location